# Retrieving ID of element on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I originally wrote a script in js that I am now rewriting using HTML5 on a canvas. Previously I had

```
<p id = "collision">Test</p>

function checkHit(){
    if (my conditions) {
        document.getElementById("collision").innerHTML = "hit!";
    }
}
```

This worked fine, but now in my canvas I have

```
c.fillStyle = "#ffff00";
c.font = "30px Arial";
c.fillText("Test", 10, 50);
```

How can I get the ID of "test" so that I can change it to "hit!" on the canvas.

Comment: You'll need to redraw the canvas, and upon redraw, use 'hit!' instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is clear the canvas, then refill it with text:

```
c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
c.fillStyle = "#ffff00";
c.font = "30px Arial";
c.fillText("Hit!", 10, 50);
```